# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'

Tags: c++, runtime, std

When I try to run this program I get this error and the program is terminated. The compiler detects no errors.. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what(): Argument value out of range

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

http://pastebin.com/ezHaFuQw

The pastebin link will show the code I am using, and I just prefer to use paste bin because I personally find it a bit neater and easier to read. Especially for code longer than 100 lines!

Comment: suggest you paste the call stack instead

Comment: Yep, definitely need the call stack from where the exception was thrown.

Comment: On line `311` you throw an exception without a condition. Is there a missing `else` statement?

Answer (score 0):

std::stoi() must be expected to throw these exceptions:

Exceptions
std::invalid_argument if no conversion could be performed  std::out_of_range if the converted value would fall out of the range of the result type or if the underlying function (std::strtol or std::strtoll) sets err no to E RANGE.